# Can we use Synonyms in other server?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, synonym

I am using some old databases so I have work with different servers.

I have created Synonyms on 'A' server and I able to do some operation on that without any problem. Now I want to use it in 'B' server, but it will now allow me access that synonyms in server 'B'. I have given all the access for that server.

Even I able to access the same table which I have created synonyms.

Snippet :
On Server 'A' : 
**CREATE SYNONYM [dbo].[EmployeeDB] FOR dbo.Employee**

On Server 'B' ;
Working with table name : select * from [B].[databaseName].[dbo].[Employee]

Not Working using synonyms name : **select * from [B].[databaseName].[dbo].[EmployeeDB]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: `You cannot reference a synonym that is located on a linked server.`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx

It is probably better to go the other way around (ie. you create a SYNONYM on B which is linked to A)
You could also use a view if you want to hide dbo.Employee.

Comment: What is the drawback for using a view? Should synonyms even exist if view can handle everything a synonym does, but even more than that?

Comment: @Tigerjz32 synonyms are alias for server objects, including stored procedures, functions, etc. A drawback would be for instance if you change the reference object but not the view.

Comment: `select * from reference.object` even if this is the definition for my view?